# How to layout Vue so pages include header/nav but ability to display stand alone pages such as registration

Tags: vue.js

My current Vue app is laid out as follows:

[image: Main layout]

Such that login Vue would be live under VContent, and aspects of the header and nav are be disabled based on auth state. For example, logout button if `store.isAuthenticaaed`. See below:

[image: Showing login]

If a **Register** exists on the login page leading to a registration Vue, how would I break that Vue out of the parent App.vue as to not display the header or nav at all? Should I move my header/wrapper down a level and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

The below answer is totally based on how I understand your requirement, happy to correct if the assumptions are wrong.

Redirecting to which page can be handled at the `router` configuration.

As per your layout, I can see you have

```
<VApp>
  <VBar />
  <VContent >
    <router-view />
  </VContent>
  <VNavigationDrawer />
</VApp>
```

Now, your store knows whether the user is authenticated or not.

So Why not simply remove `<VBar />` and `<VNavigation />` using `v-if`. However, you need to make sure that your state is having the correct state at the initial render.

I can simply create a `computed` property stating

```
showBarAndNavigation () {
  return store.isAuthenticated && this.$route.name === 'Login' && // anymore handlers
}
<VApp>
  <VBar v-if="showBarAndNavigation" />
  <VContent >
    <router-view />
  </VContent>
  <VNavigationDrawer v-if="showBarAndNavigation" />
</VApp>
```